# Algolia instasearch design like on reactjs.org with hits - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, algolia

Im making an algolia instasearch on my website. (gatsbyjs)
its pretty simple and the basics that the hits are already showed. 
Example: https://prnt.sc/sftwy9

and it automatically decreasing the hits when you start searching
https://prnt.sc/sftxl6

I want to make it like the search bar of reactjs.org. (powered by algolia) but I cant find any resources how to do it like that.
https://prnt.sc/sftzza.

do you have samples or suggestion on how to create similar to that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up doing it manually. 
I read the documentation and I used higher-order components(connectors)

https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/search-box/react/#connector
customizing it according to the design I want and added some functions similar to this
https://usehooks.com/useOnClickOutside/